# Creating a column with factor variables conditional on multiple other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-formatting

I have 4 columns, called Amplification, CNV.gain, Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency, Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency. I want to create a new column in which, if any of the values in these 4 columns are:

- greater than or equal to 5 and less than or equal to 10, it returns low:
- greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, it returns medium
- greater than 20, it returns high

An example of the final table (long_fused) would look like this:

| CNV.Gain | Amplification | Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency | Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency | Threshold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 10 | 0 | Low |
| 0 | 0 | 11 | 8 | Medium |
| 7 | 16 | 25 | 0 | High |

So far, I've tried the following code, although it seems to fill in the "Threshold" Column, is doing so incorrectly.

```
library(dplyr)
long_fused <- long_fused %>%
  mutate(Percent_sample_altered = case_when(
    Amplification>=5 & Amplification < 10 & CNV.gain>=5 & CNV.gain < 10 | CNV.gain>=5 & CNV.gain<=10 & Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency>=5 & Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency<=10| Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency>=5 & Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency<=10 ~ 'Low',
    Amplification>= 10 & Amplification<20 |CNV.gain>=10 & CNV.gain<20| Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency>= 10 & Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency<20 | Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency>=10 & Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency<20 ~ 'Medium', 
    Amplification>20 | CNV.gain >20 | Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency >20 | Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency>20 ~ 'High'))
```

As always any help is appreciated!

---

#### Data in `dput` format

```
long_fused <-
structure(list(CNV.Gain = c(3L, 0L, 7L), Amplification = c(5L, 
0L, 16L), Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency = c(10L, 11L, 25L), 
Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency = c(0L, 8L, 0L), Threshold = 
c("Low", "Medium", "High")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: You say *"if **any** of the values"* but all rows have values in more than one range. What is the rule to choose which factor level to return in those cases?

Comment: Hi Rui, so the factor level is returned based on the highest value across the 4 columns, i.e. 10,11, and 25 respectively in rows 1,2, and 3 respectively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `case_when` -

```
library(dplyr)

long_fused %>%
  mutate(max = do.call(pmax, select(., -Threshold)),
  #If you don't have Threshold column in your data just use .
  #mutate(max = do.call(pmax, .),  
         Threshold = case_when(between(max, 5, 10) ~ 'Low', 
                               between(max, 11, 15) ~ 'Medium', 
                               TRUE ~ 'High'))

#  CNV.Gain Amplification Homozygous.Deletion.Frequency
#1        3             5                            10
#2        0             0                            11
#3        7            16                            25

#  Heterozygous.Deletion.Frequency max Threshold
#1                               0  10       Low
#2                               8  11    Medium
#3                               0  25      High
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with `rowwise` followed by base function `cut`.

```
library(dplyr)

long_fused %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = max(c_across(-Threshold)),
         new = cut(new, c(5, 10, 20, Inf), labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"), left.open = TRUE))
```